# Brew cleanup unable to remove old python

Tags: permissions, homebrew

Due to long travel, I did not get a chance to update or upgrade brew for a long time and now when I run brew update or brew cleanup I get the following message:

```
 $ brew cleanup
 Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... (3,196 files, 75MB)
 Error: Could not remove /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5! Check its 
 permissions.
```

Is it safe to remove the `3.6.5` subdirectory from `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5` as `root` and then do a brew cleanup again?

EDIT: Output of `brew doctor`

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

Output of `brew cleanup -vd`

```
<Long output suppressed>   
==> This operation has freed approximately 75MB of disk space.
```

Comment: Did you try `brew doctor`? You could also run `brew cleanup -vd` and let us know the result.

Comment: I have included the output in the edited post.

Comment: Ok, then try this `sudo brew chown -R  "$USER" /usr/local/Cellar/` to restore you as the owner of the directory Cellar. Let me know.

Comment: @ePi272314, I have added the output of that command. It seems to have no effect as Homebrew seems to block sudo-based usage.

Comment: Sorry, sorry. There was an error in my previous comment run `sudo chown -R "$USER" /usr/local/Cellar/` without `brew`. Actually **try first** without `sudo` too `chown -R "$USER" /usr/local/Cellar/`. Depending on your macOS version you will need to add `sudo`.

Comment: @ePi272314, yes of course, I overlooked that too! :-)
It seems to have worked now, thank you! (PS - If you wish, please mark it as an answer so I can mark it solved.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### For this particular error

Because `homebrew` is suggesting the problem could be a permission issue you can try to solve it by restoring the proper ownership on the Homebrew Cellar directory.

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name /usr/local/Cellar/
```

or a more general solution

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" "$(brew --prefix)/Cellar"
```

It worth to remember you can use `brew doctor` to check your system for potential problems. Usually, ignore the warnings if any.

Comment: For me, this also fixed `Error: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.7/3.7.10_1`